# Validation rule that restricts a status change based on the value of another field

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, account

I have a picklist on account, one of the values is "active" and another is "proactive".

I have another field called "account minimum" (number field). In order for the status to change to "proactive" the "account minimum" field has to be a greater amount than when the status of the account was "active".

I have tried validation rules using Priorvalue but I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. In your case, you need to use [edit] and show what you have tried

Comment: If you post what you have tried, and what is not working, we can give you feedback on what to fix.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Workflow Rules, not Validation Rules.

In the WF Rule:

1. Check if Account Minimum has changed, and if Account was Active.

```
AND(
    Active_Proactive_field__c = 'Active', 
    Account_Minimum_field__c > PRIORVALUE(Account_Minimum_field__c)
)
```

2. Create a Field Update to change Account to Proactive.

This will change `Active_Proactive_field__c` if `Account_Minimum_field__c` has increased while  Account was "Active".